# ListView in android is blurry when I update the content with text from databse

Tags: android, database, android-listview, httprequest

I am new to android and I have been following tutorials to understand how things work.
My app is simple, I have a database of songs and the app connects to the database and using HTTP request it parses the json to get the desired info.

Now when I update my custom listview with the songs names fetched from the database, it shows the content but in a blurry way.

[image]

That is the customRow of the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height= "wrap_content">


 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/groupImage"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/group"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the where the ListView is configured:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   tools:context=".MainActivity">


   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/songGroupList" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the CustomAdapter that takes the songs names:

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

     private String[] info;

     public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] songGroup, String[] info) {
         super(context,R.layout.custom_row ,songGroup);

         this.info = info;
}



     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater groupInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());



         View customView = convertView;

         if(customView == null)
              customView = groupInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,  false);

         String groupName = getItem(position);

        TextView groupNameText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.group);
        TextView infoText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.info);
        ImageView groupImage = (ImageView)   customView.findViewById(R.id.groupImage);


        infoText.setText("info: " + info[position]);
        groupNameText.setText(groupName);
        groupImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.christmastree);

        return customView;
    }
 }
```

Comment: have you tried giving text color( - black) attribute to Large Text?

Comment: I tried it and it worked Thanks!!